# change form background image through a button click

Tags: c#

I want to change the form's back ground image when I click the button. I'm stuck at this error. It says:

> An object reference is required for
>   the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BackgroundImage.get'

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(25, 9);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(18, 9);
    }


    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Form1.BackgroundImage = 
    }
```

On the last part of the code, you can see that I am attempting to change the background image of the form. but it does not allow me and I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `Form1`:

```
this.BackgroundImage = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Form1` is a `Type`, not an `Instance` of an Object, you're looking for `this`.

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: Because he provided the answer himself, he just doesn't read the error message. (I blame the bad naming of the example)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Form1 use this:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.BackgroundImage = ...
```